# PHP Doesnt Work with ( ' ) symbols

Tags: php

I have a php script that uses something like this. But for some reason if i have any code with ' symbols in it, i get php errors when loading the page. So for some reason because of this i need to move all my javascripts to where `html .=''` doesnt exist.

But i need this code inside my site to work. How can i get codes with ' symbols into here?

For example below in this code we have `'linkText'` which is the issue because of ' << this symbol

```
  $html .= '<input onClick="SelectAll('linkText');" id="linkText" class="sharelinkboxes" />
    ';
```

Comment: why do you need to place an html string into a variable? just curious though

Comment: I have a site that generates images, and i have to have a way for the users to clipboard links.

Comment: Which connects to my last post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465960/link-fill-script-in-input-form/11466038#11466038

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape `'` characters with `\`:

```
$html .= '<input onClick="SelectAll(\'linkText\');" id="linkText" class="sharelinkboxes" />';
```

Comment: So editing this for google analytics ect will all work right?

Comment: Yes, if you use ' as opening tags, then you always have to add \'. Or just open with " and use normal '

Comment: Awesome :D Now i dont have to add them outside the body :)

Answer (score 7):

you have to escape the ' in a string

```
$html .= '<input onClick="SelectAll(\'linkText\');" id="linkText" class="sharelinkboxes" />';
```

Comment: So editing this for google analytics ect will all work right?

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a deeper look at what you are doing:-

```
  $html= '<input onClick="SelectAll('linkText');" id="linkText" class="sharelinkboxes" />';
```

When php encounters the second single quote just after the first bracket ('   , it says "oh! this is the closing quote for the first single quote. That is where the bug begins. So you have to escape it just like below :-

```
$html= '<input onClick="SelectAll(\'linkText\');" id="linkText" class="sharelinkboxes" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
$html .= <<< HTML
     <input onClick="SelectAll('linkText');" id="linkText" class="sharelinkboxes" />
HTML;
```

but 1 important thing do not put space after `<<< HTML` also do not put space before or after `HTML;`

or you can use

```
$html .= '<input onClick="SelectAll(\'linkText\');" id="linkText" class="sharelinkboxes" />';
```

Comment: Its not more dirty than `onClick="SelectAll(\'linkText\');"`

Comment: `<<<` solves the quotation problem and a simple solution. escape charters makes code difficult to understand, you don't understand the code on first attempt if there are too many quotation marks.

Comment: I don't see why this was *downvoted*. This is a proper solution to the issue. Also sometimes `<<<` are more appropriate than single or double quotes. +1