# Link Fill Script in input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that fills in certain links when you click on them in an input form.

But i am having one issue.

For some reason i specified the links to call the class **linkText** and specified certain values to be displayed in the input text field when clicked.

But for some reason the whole link will show including the class and value.

So for example it will display `<a class="linkInsert" value="This Value">HTML Link (websites / blogs)</a>`

instead of the value which i want which is `"This Value"`

I just want the value to display but it displays the whole code.

You can see what i mean here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUTZ7/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change html() into text()

```
$('a.linkInsert').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#linkText').val($(this).parent().text());
    });
```

or this one:

```
$('a.linkInsert').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#linkText').val($(this).attr('value'));
    });

​
```

Comment: Awesome I didnt realize that was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are placing the html of parent element into the text box.

Instead  you should use the following code that injects the value of the linked that is clicked

```
$('a.linkInsert').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#linkText').val($(this).attr("value"));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use just

```
$('a.linkInsert').click(
function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#linkText').val($(this).val());
});
```